# how to capture camera image using spacebar? I'm using ngx-webcam and angular 9

Tags: angular

I've implemented a camera capture feature in one of the angular app I'm working on.  I have a current functionality where I can click a button to capture the image.  However, I need to trigger the same capture event when a key is pressed.  Need some help how I can achieve this?

I'm using [ngx-webcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webcam) and angular 9 and followed [this demo](https://github.com/basst314/ngx-webcam-demo)  to implement the capture event.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hostbinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding)

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.space', ['$event']) onSpace(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log("sapceDown");
    this.triggerSnapshot();
}
```

I'm using triggerSnapshot funciton example [link](https://github.com/basst314/ngx-webcam-demo/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts) line 37

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Hanan